# How to execute selected methods of a given class

Tags: java, html, xml, reflection

for example,

```
class A
{
     @Test
     public int add()
    {
    ....
    }
    @Test
     public int sub()
    {
    ....
    }
    @Test
     public int div()
    {
    ....
    }

    @TestNew
     public void mul()
    {
    ....
    }
}
```

Consider this class named A..In this class we have some annotated methods and I want to display all the methods which has annotation as @Test.
This can be done by using java reflection's getAnnotation() methods.
I'm getting proper output for this. Now I've list of @Test annotated methods displayed in JSP page precede by a checkbox for each and every entry of the output.

For example:

```
        int add()   [*]

        int sub()   [*]

        int div()   []         

        [execute]
```

Consider this square brackets as checkboxes.

```
[*] -->selected checkbox..
[ ] -->not selected checkbox...
```

Now,i want to execute selected check box methods and display the result.
For this we need to generate XML files for selected methods I know only this much.
But I don't know how can we generate the xml files for selected methods get the result of the selected methods.

Once you select the checkbox and click on [execute] button ,result of the selected methods should get displayed.

How can I do this ?

Comment: what xml are you talking about ?

Comment: xml files for selected methods we need to generate

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
-<suite parallel="none" thread-count="1" name="IConnectSuite" verbose="0">-<test name="Windows+Chrome" verbose="2">-<classes><class name="com.test.auto.Mobile.testSuites.HH_TestPlan"/>-<methods><include name="runTC001_Conventional_Login_ValidInputs"/><include name="runTC001_BDD_Login_ValidInputs"/></methods></classes></test>
<!-- Test -->
</suite>

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("A");
Method  method = c.getDeclaredMethod("add", parameterTypes)
method.invoke (objectToInvokeOn, params)
```

More Info `-->` http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Comment: sorry, m not getting your logic..i think first we need to create xml file for every selected method.look we have add(),div(),sub() methods as output but I want to execute only add(),sub() methods..then what should be the next step ..from this jsp page where should I redirect the control..??